Issue with In-App Purchases in Flutter App When Running in Debug Mode
I've developed a Flutter application and have recently started testing its in-app purchase features. Here's what I've done so far:
I've successfully uploaded my app for internal testing on the Google Play Console.
I added tester emails in both the "Testers" tab under the internal testing section and in the "License Testing" section.
I installed the app from Google Play using one of the tester emails, and the in-app purchase features (InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails and InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable) worked perfectly in this version.
However, I'm facing an issue when running the app directly from Android Studio in debug mode:
The InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails still retrieves product details correctly.
But, when attempting to use InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable in debug mode, it fails and returns an error stating that the "item could not be found."
Note: It's important to mention that InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable works as expected with purchase tasks in the app that I installed from Google Play, but it does not work when running the app in debug mode directly from Android Studio.
I'm looking for insights or suggestions on why InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable does not work in debug mode or why it reports that the product is not found. Any advice on how to properly test this functionality in a development environment would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Is the primary email on the device the same as what you added to the license testing? If you have multiple accounts on the device and the debug build is connected the wrong one that could explain it.

@rmtmckenzie thanks for your response. Is the primary email on the device the same as what you added to the license testing? Yes .If you have multiple accounts on the device and the debug build is connected the wrong one that could explain it. can you please explain more what do you mean of that ?

Well I just meant that if there are two different google accounts associated with the device (i.e. a primary one you use in the play store, and then a testing one you created later on), the app could be associating with the 'primary' one rather than the testing one which could explain why it isn't working.

thanks again @rmtmckenzie You just told me a solution to another diffrence problem I was having before.. but I couldn't solve my current problem with debug mode. I haven't found a clear explanation yet

Hi @MohammedHamdan, did you find any solution for this ? Even I m facing same issue !
